# Pigeonhole principle in Ore theorem

Tags: graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle, hamiltonian-path

I was reading the proof of the *Ore theorem* from [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ore%27s_Theorem) which says
that if $G$ is a simple graph with $n\geq 3$ vertices and $d(v)+d(w)\geq n$ $\forall v,w \in V$ such that $v\neq w$ and $v, w$ are not neighbors, then $G$ is *Hamiltonian Graph*.

I understood the proof except this part:

> By the Pigeonhole Principle, for some $i$ such that $2\le i\le n−1$, $v_i$ is
> adjacent to $v_1$, and $v_{i−1}$ is adjacent to $v_n$.

I think i didn't understand the explanation of the *Pidgeonhole principle* at [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_Principle). What is an explanation of why those vertices exist using the principle (or not) applied to this case? Also, wouldn't suppose to be required $n\geq4$ vertices instead of $3$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pigeonhole principle is basically that if you have more items than containers at least 1 container has more than 1 item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the pairs of vertices $(v_{i-1}, v_i)$ for $2 \leq i \leq n-1$. There are $n-2$ of them. There are $d(v_1)$ edges between $v_1$ and some of the vertices $v_k$ for $2 \leq k \leq n-1$. In this way, $v_1$ touches $d(v_1)$ of the pairs $(v_{i-1}, v_i)$ ('touches' means $v_1$ is adjacent to $v_i$). Similarly $v_n$ touches $d(v_n)$ of the pairs $(v_{i-1}, v_i)$ (here 'touches' means $v_n$ is adjacent to $v_{i-1}$). Thus $d(v_1) + d(v_n) \geq n$ pairs are touched by $v_1$ or $v_n$. This is more than the total number of pairs, so by the pigeonhole principle, there is some pair $(v_{i-1}, v_i)$ that $v_1$ and $v_n$ both 'touch', as desired.

Comment: Perfect! I understand it now. Just one  question. Why is that $n\geq 3$ condition required for? I thought that was because of this part of the proof but we are asking for the existence of two nodes $v_{i-1}, v_i$ and $v_1, v_n$ so, wouldn't that be $n\geq 4$ in this case?

Comment: Note that $v_i$ and $v_{i-1}$ don't necessarily have to be distinct from $v_1$ and $v_n$ for the proof to work. For instance, if $v_1$ and $v_n$ touch the $i=2$ pair, then $v_n$ is adjacent to $v_1$. Either way, Ore's Theorem certainly still works for the case $n = 3$.